# Applying Winner Takes All method to raster data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I have a classified raster dataset (A). I've transformed it to polygon type data and then have applied a fishnet to it.(B) Now i want to assign a single class to a single grid (polygon type i need) with the "winner takes all" method (C).

Am i doing right with changing data type from raster to polygon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [Block Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/block-statistics.htm) on your initial raster (A) to a cell size representative of your fishnet polygons, using the “majority” method, then convert to polygons.

You might even get away with using [Resample](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm) and the “nearest” method to downsample the original raster (A) to the desired level.

If you really want to use your fishnet polygons, or if you had irregular-shaped polygons, you could use [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm), with your polygons as zones (pick a unique is for the zone field) and your original raster (A) as the value raster. Then, just join the output table back to your polygons by the unique id.

Comment: thanks for answer. Block statistics method does the job but i need every cell  to be a polygon data. Thats why i use fishnet polygon. I should assign a class value to every fishnet polygon. Then i will create points with classes from their centroids. When i tried to do zonal stats i cant find an unique id to join them.

Comment: Doesn’t your fishnet polygon layer contain an FID or OBJECTID field?